# Поменять цвет текста webView

Tags: android, webview, color

У меня есть вот такой код, который подгружает текст из файлов n0.txt, n1.txt... и выводит его в webView. Реализовано изменение размера шрифта и цвета фона (background) - все это работает. Не могу понять, как изменять цвет шрифта (по умолчанию он черный), при этом нужно, чтобы данный параметр можно было менять динамически, в зависимости от загруженной переменной с цветом background. Собственно, интересует, куда всунуть этот параметр в моем коде да так, чтобы была возможность сделать его переменной?

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_read);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        //получаем строку и формируем имя ресурса
        String resName = "n" + intent.getIntExtra("head", 0);
        Log.i("name", resName);
        Context context = getBaseContext(); //получаем контекст

        //читаем текстовый файл из ресурсов по имени
        String text = readRawTextFile(context, getResources().getIdentifier(resName, "raw", "ru.exemple.read"));

        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, text, "text/html", "en_US", null);

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings(); // инициируем настройки WebView. После этого элемента следует вставить код, подгружающий настройки из файла

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MyAppSett", MODE_PRIVATE);
        size_coef= settings.getFloat("size_coef", 1f);
        webSettings.setDefaultFontSize((int) (20*size_coef)); // устанавливаем размер текста

        settings = getSharedPreferences("MyAppColor", MODE_PRIVATE);
        color= settings.getFloat("color", WHITE);
        webView.setBackgroundColor((int) color); // устанавливаем цвет фона
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отвечу сам:
Добавил код

```
text="<font color='white'>" + text + "</font>";
```

где `white` - нужный цвет текста.
Для динамической смены темы сделаем `text` переменной и будем менять в зависимости от состояния `color` (цвет фона)

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_read);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        //получаем строку и формируем имя ресурса
        String resName = "n" + intent.getIntExtra("head", 0);
        Log.i("name", resName);
        Context context = getBaseContext(); //получаем контекст

        //читаем текстовый файл из ресурсов по имени
        String text = readRawTextFile(context, getResources().getIdentifier(resName, "raw", "ru.exemple.read"));

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MyAppColor", MODE_PRIVATE);
        color= settings.getFloat("color", WHITE);

        if (color == BLACK) {
            text="<font color='white'>" + text + "</font>";
        }
        if (color == WHITE) {
            text="<font color='black'>" + text + "</font>";
        }

        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, text, "text/html", "en_US", null);

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings(); // инициируем настройки WebView. После этого элемента следует вставить адаптер, подгружающий настройки из файла

        settings = getSharedPreferences("MyAppSett", MODE_PRIVATE);
        size_coef= settings.getFloat("size_coef", 1f);
        webSettings.setDefaultFontSize((int) (20*size_coef)); // устанавливаем размер текста

        settings = getSharedPreferences("MyAppColor", MODE_PRIVATE);
        color= settings.getFloat("color", WHITE);
        webView.setBackgroundColor((int) color); // устанавлвиаем цвет фона
    }
```

По многим причинам многие иные решения, которые легко загуглить, мне не подходят. Это самое простое, а в моем случае единственное решение